# Azure DevOps ticket styling: Setting a colour for reopened tickets

Tags: azure-devops, transparency, styling

My team is using card styling to indicate delays on tasks in Azure DevOps.
There's a loophole that clears the colours if the tasks are changed from Active to New/Closed and pulled back into Active - it resets the colouring countdown.

Is there a way to indicate if a card has been previously activated, closed and reopened again without having to set a colour on all tasks that are pulled into Active from New?

`Our current styling rules are as follows:`
`Activated Date <= @Today - 5`
`Work Item Type = Task`
`State = Active`
`your text`    [Example as per image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbCpE.png)

I started with Changed Date instead of Activated Date but the counter reset when a comment was made in the ticket.
I also tried Closed Date but the colours clear out again when pulled back into Active.
I also tried Start Date but the colours reset every time it changes status, so it resets the count when Closed (would like this to stay the same as it was on Active before it was Closed)

Comment: The styling criteria don't support querying the State history. You might consider adding a custom field for 'reopened', custom rules for the state transitions of Closed to a non-closed state that set the 'reopened' field, and then styling criteria that checks 'reopened'.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately I don't have the permission to add custom fields (company policies that's put in place, so everyone's access is limited). But it's worth looking into and seeing if we can get the limits lifted.